# Watch video inside a PDF in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf-reader

I have a video embedded PDF file, I need to open it in an iPad application. But the problem now is the PDF files are readable in the iPad app and the video file is just showing as an image. Can i do something in my code to show the video, I mean something like Media Player framework in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work. You will not be able to play the video in pdf. I think embedded media is part of the current PDF spec which Adobe has not released into the open yet. Adobe holds onto the newest most advanced version to make a business case for it's Acrobat Pro line.

That being said you can try converting the `.pdf` to `.html` and then inserting the code for a video manually.

Comment: is it possible to link the video file inside the pdf and play with in the pdf document it self

Comment: i am not aware of how this can be done. in all probabilities this cant be done on an ipad. You might need to resort to alternate ways.

Comment: thanks for upvotes, but how did manage to get his done? what alternate ways you resorted to?

Comment: we are making the pdf files so i get the details like rect, page number, video url of the video, so using the details download the corresponding video and play with in the pdf and look likes playing inside the pdf